# eglGetDisplay failed to add service on the raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, opengles

I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://jonmacey.blogspot.fr/2012/05/getting-started-with-egl-on-raspberry.html). But when I execute it I have this error :

```
> * failed to add service - already in use ?
```

The memory split is equal to 192Mb and the Pi is connected by HDMI to a monitor.

One more question, is it better to do OpenGL ES 2.0 with EGL or GLFW/GLEW ?

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial uses the old Broadcom EGL libraries (`/opt/vc`), which was all that was available in 2012. Modern Raspbian is often configured for the Mesa open-source driver, leading to a `failed to add service` error when attempting to run a program built for the former.

If you had enabled the full OpenGL driver at any point, you can run `sudo raspi-config`, revert to the legacy driver, and reboot.

It's also possible to port old projects like this one to run on Mesa EGL, but the difficulty varies depending on the codebase. A starting point would be to remove the `-L/opt/vc/lib` and `-I/opt/vc/include` references and run `sudo apt install libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev` to install the appropriate libraries.

> One more question, is it better to do OpenGL ES 2.0 with EGL or GLFW/GLEW ?

That's a loaded question and depends on your needs. One way to look at it: a GLES application written for the Pi could potentially run on other single-board computers that may lack support for full OpenGL. A GLFW/GLEW program could likewise be handy to build and test on a desktop Linux computer.